# Why does X-forwarding using ssh.exe work in cmd.exe but not Powershell?

Tags: ssh, powershell, x11-forwarding, xforwarding

I'm connecting to an ubuntu server and want to use X-forwarding to draw graphical windows on my local client machine. I'm running xming on the client.

In cmd.exe this works:

```
set DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
ssh -Y me@ubuntuserver
```

I run the same thing in Powershell, it connects successfully but then when I try to run a graphical program like xeyes on the server I get:

```
Error: Can't open display:
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 7):

Turns out the syntax for setting environment variables is different in powershell. Works with:

```
$env:DISPLAY= 'localhost:0.0'
ssh -Y aacurtis@lmmp-pipeline-ubuntu
```